# Installing Team Explorer 2008 on Windows Server 2003

Tags: visual-studio, team-explorer

I am attempting to install Team Explorer 2008 on a Windows Server 2008 box, without success, which is why I am here. The error log reveals the following:

[07/02/10,10:07:03] Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode): d:.\wcu\ppe\vside.exe exited with return value 1
[07/02/10,10:07:03] InstallReturnValue: GFN_MID VS PPE, 0x1
[07/02/10,10:07:03] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[07/02/10,10:07:03] Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode): ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : Error code 1 for this component means "Incorrect function.
"
[07/02/10,10:07:03] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[07/02/10,10:07:03] Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode): ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : Component Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) returned an unexpected value.
[07/02/10,10:07:03] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[07/02/10,10:07:03] Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode): ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : Return from system messaging: Incorrect function.

Apparently the Team Explorer 2008 is incompatible with Windows Server 2008. If you right click on the setup.exe in the TFS Explorer ISO and run a compatibility check it fails. There is a separate installer package to install the VS2008 Shell that is compatible with Windows 2008, but it fails too.

Has anyone else been able to install Team Explorer 2008 on Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

I've just rebuilt my dev server with Win 2008 R2 and have installed Team Explorer 2008. Did you apply the Visual Studio 2008 Service pack 1 before trying the install?

Comment: Yes, I did install VS 2008 SP1 before attempting to install Team Explorer 2008.